# Macbook M1 crash during sleep mode

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I know how to find a panic file on my M1 but not what to do next.

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffe0014092de0): "AppleHSBluetoothDevice::setPowerState(0xfffffe2336859240 : 0xfffffe00159f3e1c, 1 -> 0) timed out after 10301 ms" Debugger message: panic Memory ID: 0x6 OS release type: User OS version: 20C69 Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.2.0: Wed Dec 2 20:40:21 PST 2020; root:xnu-7195.60.75~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 3E6AA74DF723BCB886499A5AAB34FA34 Kernel UUID: 48F71DB3-6C91-3E62-9576-3A1DCEF2B536 iBoot version: iBoot-6723.61.3 secure boot?: YES Paniclog version: 13 KernelCache slide: 0x000000000bd90000 KernelCache base: 0xfffffe0012d94000 Kernel slide: 0x000000000c8d0000 Kernel text base: 0xfffffe00138d4000 Kernel text exec base: 0xfffffe001399c000 mach_absolute_time: 0xe0183cb78 Epoch Time: sec usec Boot : 0x601561fe 0x000646fa Sleep : 0x60161cb9 0x00040e51 Wake : 0x60162195 0x0001e857 Calendar: 0x601621a4 0x0007e7fc

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0013b06c5c CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0013b05798 CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0013b06c5c CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0013b06c5c CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0013b06c60 CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0013b06c60 CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0013b06c60 CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0013b06c60 Panicked task 0xfffffe166d2852a8: 42164 pages, 463 threads: pid 0: kernel_task Panicked thread: 0xfffffe1671c5f2c0, backtrace: 0xfffffe3086693690, tid: 46331 lr: 0xfffffe00139e9f8c fp: 0xfffffe3086693700 lr: 0xfffffe00139e9d58 fp: 0xfffffe3086693770 lr: 0xfffffe0013b0bf5c fp: 0xfffffe3086693790 lr: 0xfffffe0013afd914 fp: 0xfffffe3086693840 lr: 0xfffffe00139a37e8 fp: 0xfffffe3086693850 lr: 0xfffffe00139e99e8 fp: 0xfffffe3086693be0 lr: 0xfffffe00139e99e8 fp: 0xfffffe3086693c50 lr: 0xfffffe00141843f8 fp: 0xfffffe3086693c70 lr: 0xfffffe0014092de0 fp: 0xfffffe3086693d10 lr: 0xfffffe0014092484 fp: 0xfffffe3086693d20 lr: 0xfffffe00140b243c fp: 0xfffffe3086693d70 lr: 0xfffffe0014092428 fp: 0xfffffe3086693d90 lr: 0xfffffe0013a2b4d0 fp: 0xfffffe3086693e10 lr: 0xfffffe0013a2afac fp: 0xfffffe3086693f00 lr: 0xfffffe00139acc14 fp: 0x0000000000000000

last started kext at 719708851: com.apple.fileutil 20.036.15 (addr 0xfffffe00130ac000, size 16384) last stopped kext at 5500942896: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xfffffe0013740000, size 16384) loaded kexts: com.apple.fileutil 20.036.15 com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0 com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 4020.6 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 8.0.2f9 com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostBillboardDevice 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger 11.5 com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore 1 com.apple.driver.CoreKDL 1 com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM 5.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3 com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0 com.apple.filesystems.apfs 1677.60.23 com.apple.nke.l2tp 1.9 com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1 com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily 1.0.0 com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext 556.60.1 com.apple.security.BootPolicy 1 com.apple.BootCache 40 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2 401.63.3 com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1 com.apple.driver.AppleAVD 375 com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher 1 com.apple.AGXG13G 172.20.14 com.apple.driver.ApplePMP 1 com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio 437.96 com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2 1 com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware 1 com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1 com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp 437.96 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP 140.0 com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver 4.6.0 com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3 1 com.apple.driver.AppleSummitLCD 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103 1 com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103 1.58 com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO 1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1 com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES 1 com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1 com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule 1 com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe 1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1 com.apple.driver.AppleSynopsysMIPIDSI 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C 1.0.0d2 com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1 com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons 1.0.0d1 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1 com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1 com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity 1 com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2 1 com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 310 com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac 1 com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard 222 com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver 4400.28 com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver 4400.28 com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 4020.6 com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver 8.0.2f9 com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 900.12 com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin 900.11 com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99 com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily 1 com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio 14.32 com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager 1.0.1 com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1 com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0 com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.2f9 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport 8.0.2f9 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4 com.apple.driver.AppleBTM 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl 1 com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI 1 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug 1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 8.1.4 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 8.1.4 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1 com.apple.nke.ppp 1.9 com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy 172.20.14 com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64 172.20.14 com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter 3 com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy 1 com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1 com.apple.driver.AppleSPU 1 com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy 1 com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 20.21.1 com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily 2.1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio 437.96 com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI 4400.35 com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport 4400.35 com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport 4400.35 com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHPM 3.4.4 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 437.96 com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio 80.34 com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP 343.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleDCP 1 com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit 1 com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM 3.0 com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface 2.77.0 com.apple.driver.AppleH10PearlCameraInterface 14.70.0 com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface 4.51.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily 2.0.0 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM 1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI 1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost 1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub 1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice 1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1 com.apple.driver.AppleSART 1 com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR 1 com.apple.driver.watchdog 1 com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy 1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 7.2.8 com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC 1 com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2 com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA 1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1 com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1 com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DFR 140.0 com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily 343.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103 510.72 com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController 1.0.2 com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1 com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager 1 com.apple.driver.corecapture 1.0.4 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE 1 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1 com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily 900.11 com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 585 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 8.0.2f9 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.2f9 com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit 68.5.0 com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1 com.apple.driver.AppleSSE 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore 2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM 511.60.2 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver 184.40.6 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 436.40.6 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 436.40.6 com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30 com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0 com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost 1 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties 1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9 com.apple.driver.RTBuddy 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1 com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.4 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11 com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2 com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor 1 com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor 2 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0 com.apple.AUC 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1 com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17 com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext 1 com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 289.3 com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily 1 com.apple.security.quarantine 4 com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5 com.apple.kext.CoreTrust 1 com.apple.security.AppleImage4 3.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform 1.0.2 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1 com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 47 com.apple.kec.pthread 1 com.apple.kec.corecrypto 11.1 com.apple.kec.Libm 1

** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 315257 (Uncompressed 801776) **
```

What is the possible reason of the crash ?

Comment: Thanks for posting the panic log. I’ve formatted it since the lengthy details aren’t very helpful for next steps.

Comment: I've got the exact same issue.  If you find a solution, please do post!

Answer (score 1):

These are hard to debug specifically, but if you want to, set up the Mac to save the core dump file (or send them to a network server that collects cores) and use a second Mac to inspect the call trace.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/debugging_a_custom_kernel_extension
- https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

The second link covers how to get the KDK which is the kit that helps debug and log more details. You have a report, but it’s likely there’s not enough detail to trace back what actually happened. Everyone can see the debris from an accident, but all the evidence wasn’t collected by default. The KDK sets up a forensic situation where you could definitively answer what happened after the fact.

On Intel, the nature of a panic is the same at a high level, but very different in the specifics for your Apple Silicon based mini with an M1 CPU. Here is an archived article from Intel days that explains the basics very well. Forgive the kitchen metaphor if you’re well read on machine language faults already or the idea of kernel space crashes.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2063/_index.html

> In UNIX, a panic is an unrecoverable system error detected by the kernel as opposed to similar errors detected by user space code.

The core is not in a logical state to continue, basically. Why did this happen? Odds are it’s hardware putting a value in the software didn’t ever expect to see. Like if you told the code to expect one to three fruits as input to make a smoothie and instead a dead rat showed up to be processed. The kitchen shuts down to figure out what the heck is going on rather than make a dead rat smoothie as previously instructed from one to three fruits.

> However, most panics are the result of unhandled processor exceptions in kernel code, such as references to invalid memory addresses. These are typically indicative of a bug somewhere in the call chain leading up to the panic.

So, Apple might make code to say, dispose of dead rodents and then wait for more fruits to make smoothies. Then the next time, a “dead rat exception” would be handled until say 4 fruits show up. Then more handlers need to be written or the kernel changed yet again...

Comment: You had me at "dead rats" !

Answer (score 1):

The panic string shows a timeout while waiting for the Bluetooth stack to power down. This is quite likely a bug on Apple’s side and there isn’t much you can do about it yourself beyond reporting it to Apple. If this is reproducible, that’s helpful for us & them to know.

As a workaround, you can try disabling Bluetooth and see if the problem goes away.